# Shortest path for positive edge weights, largest path weight known

Tags: graph-theory

Given a directed graph G(V,E) with (positive) weighted edges, is there an algorithm that computes the shortest paths from a single vertex to every other, given the total weight of the largest shortest path to be K, in O(K+V+E) time?

Comment: Wouldn't stack overflow be better for this?

Comment: Someone already asked it there. But no one answers.

Comment: Try Djikstra's algorithm but keep track of the depth of the search. Stop when it exceeds $K$ because no shortest path can be longer.